# Get the array element that appears first in an HTML string

Tags: arrays, perl, indexing

I have this array:

```
@tags = (
    '<div id=',
    '<article id=',
    '<div class=',
    '<article class='
);
```

and an HTML string.

I want to find the array element that appears earliest in the string.

Does anyone have an elegant way of doing this?

Comment: unclear if you *just* want the lowest index or if you also actually need all the indexes

Comment: Or if you just want a string and really no index at all.

Comment: And btw: is there an element in your array that supposedly doesn't contain HTML?

Comment: If you only need to output the element with the lowest index then why would you loop every element?

Comment: I only want the string with the lowest index (don't need to know the index itself or any others). The one element that is not HTML is a typo.. all will be HTML. Greetings.

Comment: I need to loop every element to find out which element is seen first in the HTML string.

Comment: Please include your desired output, as you can see from the comments what you are asking for is not clear.

Comment: I don't really know how to clarify this. It needs to find the index of every element using index($html, $element), and return the one that is seen first (thus having the lowest index in the string).

Comment: So if $html would be 'dhgfe', and the array would contain ('f','g','e') it would return 'g' because that is first in $html.

Comment: I think it's pretty clear now.

Comment: `my %index = map { index($html, $_) => $_ } @tags;
say $index{(sort grep { $_ >= 0 } keys %index)[0]};`

Comment: `my $re = join '|', map quotemeta, @tags; print $html =~ /($re)/;`

Comment: @P.Henderson: I've modified your question to explain better what I think you want. Is that correct? The problem was that everyone thought by `index` you meant an array index. The `index` function is used relatively rarely in Perl as it has such extensive regular expression support.

Comment: @Borodin: I thought it was clear s/he meant index into the string (but your edit was good, now that we know what the question is).  and your code above should be an answer, not a comment

Comment: @ysth: I think at least Blam thought it involved array indices, and I know I did at first. And I can't publish an answer until this question gets reopened :-/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest option is to build a regex from the array and let the regex engine report the first string it finds. Like this

```
my $re = join '|', map quotemeta, @tags;
print $html =~ /($re)/;
```

Comment: Hello, thank you so much for this. It is precisely what I need. I tried to vote for it but I do not have enough reputation. Also thank you for fixing the question, I understand the confusion now.

Comment: @P.Henderson even if you can't vote, you should be able to accept it as the correct answer; click on the big checkmark to the left of the answer.